# Running a socket.io server in a real live server, instead of localhost?

Tags: node.js, express, server, socket.io

I found a coding from tutorials point to run a a simple socket.io chat server in localhost, I installed necessary environments like nodejs, express, init package.json and I started the server from terminal using command-"node app.js", then I accessed the index page in my localhost it showed the chat page, it is working fine. But the thing is I want to use this is in a live server for my office, to chat within the office. Is this code is enough for that. I am new to this socket.io and nodejs. My office has live server for hosting their website, this code opens and listens to port 3000. It will be highly helpful if you could tell me how to run this in a real server.

**Index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello world</title>
   </head>

   <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   <script>
      var socket = io();
      function setUsername() {
         socket.emit('setUsername', document.getElementById('name').value);
      };
      var user;
      socket.on('userExists', function(data) {
         document.getElementById('error-container').innerHTML = data;
      });
      socket.on('userSet', function(data) {
         user = data.username;
         document.body.innerHTML = '<input type = "text" id = "message">\
         <button type = "button" name = "button" onclick = "sendMessage()">Send</button>\
         <div id = "message-container"></div>';
      });
      function sendMessage() {
         var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
         if(msg) {
            socket.emit('msg', {message: msg, user: user});
         }
      }
      socket.on('newmsg', function(data) {
         if(user) {
            document.getElementById('message-container').innerHTML += '<div><b>' + 
               data.user + '</b>: ' + data.message + '</div>'
         }
      })
   </script>

   <body>
      <div id = "error-container"></div>
      <input id = "name" type = "text" name = "name" value = "" 
         placeholder = "Enter your name!">
      <button type = "button" name = "button" onclick = "setUsername()">
         Let me chat!
      </button>
   </body>
</html>
```

**app.js Server**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.sendfile('index.html');
  });

  users = [];
 io.on('connection', function(socket) {
 console.log('A user connected');
 socket.on('setUsername', function(data) {
  console.log(data);

  if(users.indexOf(data) > -1) {
     socket.emit('userExists', data + ' username is taken! Try some              
  } else {
     users.push(data);
     socket.emit('userSet', {username: data});
  }
 });

  socket.on('msg', function(data) {
  //Send message to everyone
  io.sockets.emit('newmsg', data);
  })
 });

http.listen(3000, function() {
console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

Comment: the server is already 'live' on the local network at the ip of the server computer. (run `ipconfig` or equivalent to see what ip). if you have a multi-router internal network you may also want to also setup the routing tables. (if a router or server in the office is working as your networks DNS you could also create an internal site address)

Comment: thank you so much, it worked when I accessed the ip of the network with the port 3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem through nginix( A reverse proxy server). Nginx have .conf file which contains the server realted configuration.

```
server { listen 3000; server_name io.yourhost.com; }
```

To run:

```
Sudo service nginx start
```

It will start your server on given IP or Domain name.

Comment: I have the same issue on the apache, Hosted node js code on the aws, What do we need to do for that?

Answer (score 1):

Change the declaration variable **socket** by 
`var socket = io(Server IP + ':port');`

Example:

```
var socket = io('127.0.0.1:3000);
```

I using socket.io version 2.0.2